# Access ViewModel instance from within the ItemTemplate.DataTemplate of ItemsControl

Tags: mvvm, binding, command, viewmodel

I have data template defined in a separate file (Styles.xaml).
Page has an instance of ViewModel (I'm using MVVM pattern).
My view model contains command which I'm trying to bind to from withing the data template.

How can I access it?

`ElementName` and `RelativeSource` are not resolved by my binding.

Page Xaml:

```
xmlns:partial="clr-namespace:PhoneApp7.Partial"

...
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.DataContext>
    <viewModel:DynamicViewModel />
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.DataContext>
...

<ItemsControl x:Name="ItemsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
             <partial:DoItItemTemplate />
        </DataTemplate>
       </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

View Model:

```
public class DynamicViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> Items
    {
        get
        {
            return new ObservableCollection<string>
            {
                "item 1",
                "item 2",
                "item 2",
            };
        }
    }

    public RelayCommand<string> DoIt { get; set; }

    public DynamicViewModel()
    {
        DoIt = new RelayCommand<string>(OnDoIt);
    }

    private void OnDoIt(string args)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Yay! {0}", args));
    }
}
```

Item User Control Xaml

```
<UserControl x:Class="PhoneApp7.Partial.DoItItemTemplate"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

    <Button Content="{Binding}" Command="{Binding DataContext.DoIt, ElementName=ItemsControl}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"></Button>

</UserControl>
```

You can find complete sample by the following link:
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/83972129/binding_issue.zip

Comment: Can your show minimal code in order demonstrate the problem?

Comment: Maybe you could have an another approach.
Define a new ViewModel (for example `StringViewModel`) for `strings` in `Items`.
So istead of `ObservableCollection<string> Items`,
use `ObservableCollection<StringViewModel> Items`.

From `StringViewModel` you can bind a string value, and command `DoIt`
to `DoItItemTemplate`. Note that you can reuse `DoIt` command from `DynamicViewModel`
if you have a reference to `DynamicViewModel` in `StringViewModel`, 
simply pass that reference in constructor of `StringViewModel` and store
in a property

Comment: I know several workarounds but I'm looking for permanent solution. I'm trying to fix it from project to project without any luck.

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest solution to this problem (IMHO) is to give the UserControl a Command dependency property, and have the Command property of the Button bind to that.

From the MainPage, you can then bind the new Command property of the UserControl to the desired command, by binding to DataContext.DoIt, with ElementName=ItemsControl.

This will also offer some extra flexibility to bind to other commands should the situation demand it, and not hardcode the command to bind to in the template itself.

The user control:

```
public partial class DoItItemTemplate : UserControl
{
    // ...

    private static void CommandChangedCallback(...)
    {
        DoItItemTemplate owner = (DoItItemTemplate)d;
        owner.CommandChanged((ICommand)e.OldValue, (ICommand)e.NewValue);
    }

    private void CommandChanged(ICommand oldValue, ICommand newValue)
    {

    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(...)
    public ICommand Command
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(CommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(CommandProperty, value); }
    }

    // ...

}


<UserControl x:Class="PhoneApp7.Partial.DoItItemTemplate"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             x:Name="root">

    <Button Content="{Binding}"
            Command="{Binding Path=Command, ElementName=root}"
            CommandParameter="{Binding}"></Button>

</UserControl>
```

And in the main page:

```
       <ItemsControl x:Name="ItemsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <partial:DoItItemTemplate Command="{Binding DataContext.DoIt, ElementName=ItemsControl}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: I'm trying to implement it for different controls having different templates. Moreover it is not only about one command. I wan't to access DataContext itself, not a single property.

Comment: Then I suspect you're out of luck. Unless you introduce a property that basically binds to the "outer" DataContext in a similar fashion as the Command property I suggested.

Answer (score 0):

you can use class helper if u need; it will be useful specially if you need to this command in many controls or datatemplates.